# What's a good way to get and display all the folders and files of a directory in a Vue.js + Electron app?

Tags: vue.js, electron

I have a Vue.js + Electron app ([electron-vue boilerplate](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue))

What are the best practices of getting and displaying directory's folders and files?

Basically I want it to behave like a File Explorer (Windows) or Finder (Mac). You open a folder you get all the content displayed.

---

Let's say we have:

- the main view called `App.vue` with a router inside of it.
- there's an `open folder` button in `App.vue`.
- And we also have `FileExplorer.vue` component that is getting displayed as a route inside that `App.vue`

How do I make this `FileExplorer.vue` component to get and display files and folders of, let's say, directory `C:\test folder` (on Windows) when we hit that  `open folder` button in `App.vue`?

---

I know that I should use Node for that, but how exactly? What do I import and how do I use Vue to make it all work together?

All the projects on Github are too complicated for a newbie to understand how they work. For example [this](https://github.com/iliran11/great-file-explorer) one is quite simple looking, but there's so much code in there that you don't even know where to start

## Update:

I managed to get the content of a folder doing this:

```
<v-btn @click="readDirectory"></v-btn>

[...]

const fs = require('fs-extra')
export default {
  name: "FileExplorer",
  data () {
    return {
      dir:'C:/test',
      files:[],
      file:""
    }
  },
  methods: {
    readDirectory() {
      fs.readdir(this.dir, (err, dir) => {
      console.log(dir);
      for(let filePath of dir)
      console.log(filePath)
      this.files = dir
      })
    },
  }
}
```

And I displayed it like this:

```
 <v-btn v-for="file in files" :key="file.id">
    {{file}}
 </v-btn>
```

But it doesn't really behave like a real file explorer...I get the folders and files on button click but I can't do anything with all those folders and files.

How do I make all the folders that it gets on click to behave in a similar way (to get its content) ?

And how do I display folders and files differently?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to allow a user to select a folder in Electron I would suggest using the [`showOpenDialog`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowopendialogbrowserwindow-options-callback) API.

In the renderer process, you need to use the `remote` API to access the `dialog` API.

```
const { remote } = require('electron')

remote.dialog.showOpenDialog({
  properties: ['openDirectory'],
  defaultPath: current
}, names => {
  console.log('selected directory:' + names[0]);
});
```

If you want to display the contents of a directory within your app you're going to have to use the node [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module and read the directory contents.

```
fs.readdir(path[, options], callback)
```

Will callback with all the file and directory paths which you'll then have to iterate over to get more info or to traverse recursively to get their contents. There are are node modules which make this process a little easier than writing it all yourself.

Once you've got an object tree containing all your files and directories you can use this to create a UI using vue.js.

Comment: Sorry if it's confusing, I've edited the question. I kind of want to just display all the content, like a File Explorer on windows or Finder on Mac. Not sure what's the best way

Comment: Added details for directory listing